# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, eclipse, mysql-workbench

I'm pretty sure my user & password are correct but i keep getting this error saying i dont have access to it in eclipse

[image attached of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsM6p.png)

Comment: Check the password again.

Comment: The link might help